# Why was Fleur's little sister Gabrielle even at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

I am surprised that I didn't find this question using the search.

***Why was Fleur's little sister Gabrielle even at Hogwarts?***

If I remember correctly she must have been only 8 years old, and all the other students from Beauxbatons were older than her.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! This is a nice first question.

Comment: Thank you! I am usually more of a quiet spectator of most stackexchange sites.

Comment: [Dupe over on M&TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84349/why-does-gabrielle-delacour-arrive-at-hogwarts-with-her-sister-in-the-goblet-of?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa): the answer there says she arrived after the main school just for the task though gives no evidence.

Comment: "all the other students from Beauxbatons were older than her" is that so? I'm not saying it's not the case, but is it explicitly mentioned anywhere that a) this school, just like Hogwarts, only takes students at the age of 10 or 11 and that b) only kids older than 8 arrived with them at Hogwarts. I don't remember any scene from inside that carriage, who knows how many children had to live inside that thing

Comment: @Raditz_35 The only students from Beauxbatons and Durmstrang were their potential champions. Given that the age restriction on putting your name in the Goblet of Fire was (supposed to be) 17, it wouldn't make any sense to bring students who had no possible chance of being selected as your school's Champion. I'm pretty sure Karkaroff says that if he'd known those under 17 would be allowed to put their names forward he would have brought more students with him after Harry is selected as the fourth participant.

Comment: I am reffering to the scene were they are arriving in the great hall together. I didn't notice other young students beside her. That being said, is has been quite some time since I have seen the movie or read the book.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I am aware about the logic behind such an assumption, however I asked if this is explicitly stated? Some sports teams e.g. bring their fans along to games because having some people behind you can help and it was shown that they were so eager to win that they cheated, so it isn't so completely unreasonable that they brought fans=younger students  that I would absolutely exclude the possibility

Comment: I think the OP is basically correct that the issue is "fudged" a bit in the movies.  Great spot!

Comment: Beauxbatons...  Durmstrang... Could JKR have gotten any more obvious with her names?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

## She seemed to be “brought in” for the Second Task.

Fleur’s sister didn’t seem to arrive at Hogwarts with the rest of the students - we only see her at the Second Task, when she’s held as the hostage for Fleur. The other three hostages were already at Hogwarts since they were all Hogwarts students, but it seems like Fleur’s sister was brought in specifically for the task, perhaps since there was no one at Hogwarts she cared about much.

> “A choir of merpeople were singing in the middle, calling the champions towards them, and behind them rose a crude sort of statue; a gigantic merperson hewn from a boulder. Four people were bound tightly to the tail of the stone merperson.
>
> Ron was tied between Hermione and Cho Chang. There was also a girl who looked no older than eight, whose clouds of silvery hair made Harry feel sure that she was Fleur Delacour’s sister. All four of them appeared to be in a very deep sleep. Their heads were lolling onto their shoulders, and fine streams of bubbles kept issuing from their mouths.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 26 (The Second Task)*</sup></sub>

After the Second Task was over, we don’t see Fleur’s sister again until the champions’ families are invited to Hogwarts to watch the final task.

> “On the other side of the room, Fleur was jabbering away in French to her mother. Fleur’s little sister, Gabrielle, was holding her mother’s hand. She waved at Harry, who waved back.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 31 (The Third Task)*</sup></sub>

After having saved her, Harry would be more likely (though not guaranteed) to notice her presence at Hogwarts since he “knew” her - however, she’s not mentioned as being at Hogwarts until the families come for the final task.

## In the movie, though, she came in with the Beauxbatons students.

In the movie version of *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, Gabrielle comes in with the students, and is doing flips.

[image]

She’s also shown in the Beauxbatons uniform, which may imply that the movie intended her to be a student.

[image]

However, in the movie, there don’t seem to be any other Beauxbatons students as young as her, so if she is supposed to be a student, that would make her the youngest one brought to Hogwarts by far.

As Valorum suggests in the comments, it’s possible they suspected Fleur would be chosen as champion, and brought her sister specifically in preparation for the Second Task.

Comment: Presumably Fleur was the obvious choice for tri-wizard champion. Bringing her sister makes good sense

Comment: @Valorum So that they’d have her for the Second Task, or for another reason?

Comment: If you expected student x to be your champion, you'd probably bring along their family member or close friend as hostage. Don't forget that Beauxbatons are well aware of the terms of the tournament and must have a very strong idea of who the cup is going to choose

Comment: @Valorum Ah okay, that makes sense! :)

Comment: The evidence seems to me to suggest that Gabrielle was at least 11 in the movie version of *Goblet of Fire*.  Is there any evidence she was younger?

Comment: @HarryJohnston seems to have hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Bella, are you saying that when we **first** see her (with the flips), she's not dressed as a student - indeed implying she's "come along" for some reason?  But then .. later she **is** dressed as a student?  Is that right?  Thanks.

Comment: @Fattie Yes that’s exactly what I’m saying! When we first see her when the Beauxbatons students arrive (in the first picture in this answer) she’s dressed differently than all the other students. Then later, she’s dressed in the Beauxbatons uniform. (A possibility is that she was dressed differently for the entrance so she could do her flips more easily.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Her age is never specified in the movie - she’s about eight in the books. In addition, we don’t know what age students start attending Beauxbatons. They may have a different starting age than Hogwarts.

Comment: Well, she's obviously too young to be a potential champion, so she must be there in order to be with her big sister.  It probably doesn't matter what her exact age is, it just seemed that the OP was assuming that the movies were (or "should be") the same as the books - and the Wiki does the same - which I think is an unwarranted assumption.

Comment: In the book: This makes perfect sense - in the films, it's a plot hole ;) - Good answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Fleur was competing as Beauxbatons' champion in the first Triwizard Tournament in ages. Although this is not mentioned explicitly in the books, surely her family would come over for the occasion, to cheer her on?

Comment: But Gabrielle was attending already before the Goblet of Fire chose Fleur. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Pudora According to the Q on M&TV in the books she is brought over just for the task but in the films she was there from the beginning.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Ah, I've never seen all of the films.

Comment: @SQB Me neither that's what M&TV and google told me :) If I could find a quote for evidence I'd add an answer but I can't at the moment so giving you the information to expand your own answer

Answer (score 3):

Fleur's little sister was doing gymnastics when they arrived at hogwarts.
So I'm guessing she's the school's mascot since she's too young to go to the same school as her sister.

Comment: Judging from the other discussion, both on this question and on the one on Movies.SE, this only applies to the film. Is there an explanation in the books?

Answer (score 3):

Each champion had their most precious possession -- the person they valued most -- taken by the merpeople and held for rescue by their champion. Harry's best friend, Ron, was chosen, and Hermione was chosen for Krum to rescue. Cedric's girlfriend, Cho Chang, and Fleur's little sister, Gabrielle, were also selected for the task. I imagine she was "flown in" for the task.

Answer (score 2):

While there's no mention of it, it wouldn't be unreasonable to imagine that Beauxbatons takes students at a significantly younger age than Hogwarts.

In the UK we have a clear separation between Primary and Secondary School, starting at around age 11/12. Muggle France does something very comparable, but that's not to say that wizarding France might not combine the two and reduce the distinction, after all, with such a small population it may not make sense to have more than one school.

Alternatively they make take an attitude that while a wizarding child might not come into their magic until their second decade, the training may begin much earlier.

One might liken it to Ballet or learning an instrument, where in general starting younger is more desirable.